# How can I combine scrolling effect and mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have managed to do a scrolling effect as you can see in this link [here](https://codepen.io/melodiacapoeira/pen/EMQjxQ?editors=1111).

On another link([see here](https://codepen.io/melodiacapoeira/pen/QoQEOV)) I have another animation that happens on mouse move.

On top of my scrolling effect, I want the first image to have the mouse move effect.
How can I combine that?

I am seeing it quite challenging because the styling for both are completely different. In one template I work actual images in the froont-end but in the other one I work with image background.

JS:

```
var zoom_value = 1;
var boxFullHeight = $('header').height();
var boxHalfHeight = $('header').height() / 2;
var domHeight = $('html').scrollTop();

//scrollController will check the value when scrolling up or down
var scrollController = 0;

//max number that the scroll happens before images change
var max_scrollController = 4;

//this will enable/disable the scrollbar after a certain period
var controller = 0;

$(window).on('wheel', function(e) {

    var delta = e.originalEvent.deltaY;

    function add_styling(zoom_value){
         $("#firstbox img").css({
            "font-size": zoom_value +"px",
            "transform": "scale(" + zoom_value + ")",
            "transition": "all .9s"
        });               
    }

    if (delta > 0 && controller < 10){ 
        controller++;
        zoom_value = zoom_value + 0.1;  
        scrollController++;
        add_styling(zoom_value);

        if(scrollController >= max_scrollController){
            $('.img2').addClass('hide_image');
        }
        return false;
    }
    else if(delta < 0) {
        if (zoom_value > 1) {
            controller--;
            zoom_value = zoom_value - 0.1;
            scrollController--;

            add_styling(zoom_value);
            if(scrollController < max_scrollController){
                $('.img2').removeClass('hide_image');
            }
        }
        else{
            zoom_value = 1;
            add_styling(zoom_value);
        }
    }

});
```

CSS:

```
html,body,header, #header_box, .image_box, img {
    height: 100%;
}
#firstbox{
  background: red;
    width: 100%;
}

#second_box{
  background: blue;
}

#third_box{
  background: black;
}

.general{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.image_box{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
}

.hide_image {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="firstbox" class="general">
        <header>
            <div id="header_box">
                <div class="image_box">
                    <img class="img1" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/07/13/38/landscape-2124022_960_720.jpg" alt="image here">
                </div>
                <div class="image_box box2">
                    <img class="img2" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/05/20/10/blue-2375119_960_720.jpg" alt="image here">
                </div>             
            </div>

        </header>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias ut accusamus non error laboriosam in commodi ad, sint, neque voluptates deserunt magnam minima nulla officia nobis fugit enim optio assumenda.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="second_box" class="general">

    </div>

    <div id="third_box" class="general">

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: If you want both of them to work at the same time you need to figure out if you want to use images or background-images. I would suggest actual images since it's better SEO wise. Then it's just a matter of combining `.on('wheel hover')` or `.on('wheel mouseenter')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your javascript:

```
$('.box2').on('mousemove', function(e){
  var x = e.originalEvent.x,
      y = e.originalEvent.y,
      w = this.offsetWidth,
      h = this.offsetHeight,
      targetX = w / 2 - x,
      targetY = h / 2 - y;

  $(this).css({
    'transform': 'scale(1.2) translate(' + targetX/10 +'px, ' + targetY/10 +'px)'
  });
});
```

Comment: It seems like I have to know a lot more about JavaScript animation and events. Where can I find more info about mouse events and respective handles etc?

Comment: You can see all possible javascript events here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp - there is a lot :)